# Dart custom sorting of a list

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart

I want to build a suggestion builder where I want to display search suggestions on changing the text in TextField. I want to search on the basis of `contains` method but I want to sort that particular list on the basis of `startsWith`, If I only use `startsWith` it neglects all other `contains`, How can I apply both simultaneously?
I have a List,

```
List<String> list = ["apple", "orange", "aaaaorange", "bbbborange","cccccorange"]
```

Now If I put only `ora` in search it's returning me in the following order,

```
aaaaorange
bbbborange
cccccorange
orange
```

What I want.

```
orange
aaaaorange
bbbborange
cccccorange
```

Code:

```
            return list
                .where((item) {
              return item.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
            }).toList(growable: false)
                  ..sort((a, b) {
                    return a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase());
                  });
```

Comment: Should `apple` appear in the second list? It doesn't contain `ora`.

Comment: Sorry, Mistake. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easiest to think of the two queries separately, and then combine the results:

```
  var list = <String>[
    'apple',
    'orange',
    'aaaaorange',
    'bbbborange',
    'cccccorange',
  ];
  var pattern = 'ora';

  var starts = list.where((s) => s.startsWith(pattern)).toList();
  var contains = list
      .where((s) => s.contains(pattern) && !s.startsWith(pattern))
      .toList()
        ..sort((a, b) => a.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toLowerCase()));

  var combined = [...starts, ...contains];
  print(combined);
```

Comment: You may want to sort the starts list too, of course.

Comment: Some modifications were required according to my code and this is a perfect solution. Bundle of thanks.